# Using ng-repeat with objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble diagnosing an issue when using `ng-repeat` within my controller. I am trying a proof-of-concept to display an array of objects' keys and values within a tag. This is my first go with Angular.

I have a controller that returns an array of simple objects. I am trying to generate tags using values from these objects.

**activitiesController**

```
app.controller("activityController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {    

$scope.activities = [
    { name: "hi" },
    { name: "hello" }
]

}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<p ng-controller="activityController">

<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in activities">
    <span>{{ key }} {{ val }}</span>        
</div>

</p>
```

Am I missing something? I get no errors but no data is ever displayed on my page.

---

**SOLUTION**

It's best to use this format instead (but the problem lied in nesting a `div` inside a `p`).

```
<div ng-controller="activityController">

    <div ng-repeat="activity in activities">
        <span>{{ activity.name }}</span>        
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s6b9gd6q/1/

Comment: Might there be any reason why nothing is showing up? I'm baffled why this is displaying nothing on my end.

Comment: The notation `(key, val)` within an ng-repeat is to iterate the properties of an object, not the items in an array which is what activities is defined as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using paragraph (p) use a div. You can't nest divs in a paragraph:

```
<div ng-controller="activityController">

  <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in activities">
      <span>{{ key }} {{ val }}</span>        
  </div>

</div>
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yoFlPvMOC2rgv90E0Abu?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

```
<p ng-controller="activityController">

    <div ng-repeat="activity in activities">
        <span>{{ activity.name }}</span>        
    </div>

</p>
```

This is the way to output.